# How do you iterate over all values produced by a function?

Tags: for-loop, go, dry

I am new to go, and I have found myself writing a few `for` loops which look like this:

```
for element, err := producer.Produce(); err == nil; element, err = producer.Produce() {
    process(element)
}
```

where `producer.Produce()` is a function like `reader.ReadString('\n')` or `fmt.Fscan(Reader, &token)`. I would much rather like to write

```
for element := range elements {
    process(element)
}
```

but for now, I would be satisfied to know if there is a cleaner way to iterate over the output of these kinds of functions in go. In particular, is there a nice way to get rid of this annoying duplication in the init statement and the post statement of the for statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything quite as clean as what you're looking for. The idiomatic way to write it is:

```
for {
    element, err := producer.Produce()
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    process(element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to create a channel from such a method:

```
elements := make(chan elementType)

val send func()
send = func() {
    if element, err := producer.Produce(); err == nil {
        elements <- element
        go send()
    } else {
      close(elements)
    }
}
go send()

for element := range elements {
    process(element)
}
```

Comment: This works, and if you're happy with the speed that's great. But it is quite a bit slower than my answer due to the channel.

Comment: As a rule of thumb this kind of code is very bad. It slows down your code without providing any advantage other than a slightly prettier `for` loop.